# VM cannot start because of the saved state in C:\

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtualbox

I have a problem regarding my Virtual Box guest OS. I'm using Windows XP, and when I start my Vbox I encountered this error`

> VM cannot start because the saved state in c:\

I followed the suggestion to delete the .sav file in the following location:

```
C:\users\[username]\Virtualbox VMs\windows xp\snapshots
```

However, that doesn't solve the problem. The error still comes up when I try to start Windows XP in VBox.

How would I solve this?

Comment: lente wala klaro.

Comment: Can you include the relevant lines from the log file (somewhere near the snapshots folder you mentioned most likely) or put the log file online somewhere it could be examined?

Comment: you forgot to say that you are using W7. do you have other VM's? they "function"?